OpenMP tasks crash once the "spawning routine" exits
I have the following program structure:
type(mytype) :: x(10)

!$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT(SHARED)
!$OMP MASTER
do i = 1, 10
   call sub1(x(i)) ! some stuff that cannot be parallelized
   call sub2(x(i)) ! some stuff that can be parallelized once sub1 has completed
!$OMP END MASTER
!$OMP END PARALLEL

[.....]

subroutine sub2(x)
   type(mytype), intent(inout) :: x
   integer :: j, k
   integer, allocatable :: v(:)
   allocate( v(10000) ) 
   v(:) = ... ! filling up v
   do j = 1, 1000
      !$OMP TASK DEFAULT(NONE) SHARED(x) PRIVATE(k) FIRSTPRIVATE(j,v)
         !...working on x
      !$OMP END TASK
   end do
end subroutine

But it doesn't behave as expected:

the master thread is exiting sub2() only after many of the 1000 tasks (which take several seconds each) have completed. Is it because it takes a lot of time to initialize the tasks (in particular duplicating the firstprivate arrays for each task) ?
more annoying, as soon as the master thread is exiting sub2(), the program crashes in one of tasks with a memory error ("null pointer dereference or unaligned memory access" message in the debugger). I don't get why it happens, as:

all the dummy arguments that are used in a task are declared as SHARED, and therefore should remain accessible as long as the program is in the parallel region
all the local variables that are used in a task are declared as PRIVATE or FIRSTPRIVATE, and therefore should have the same lifetime as the task itself



What am I missing here?
The compiler is Intel ifort 2018

I did not study the specs and I do not use tasks, but are the private local variables really supposed to outlive their subroutine? BTW, the compiler is pretty old.

I'm not sure... It's not clear to me at which moment the private copy is effectively made: when the task is created, or when the task is started? If it is the latter, then it can explain the crash.

Actually, not only it can, but it does explain the crash. And the whole structure of my code then does not allow this approach. I could put a taskwait at the end of sub2() but I originally wanted the master thread to execute the next iteration of sub1 without having to wait the task completions.

When a task is created, it copies the private informations. Shared variable are private information too but internally there are pointers. A task can be directly scheduled or later at scheduling points. The end of a parallel section is a scheduling point. x will certainly be referenced by a pointer and not be valid after the function call causing a dangling pointer. I'm not very familiar with Fortran where pointers are a bit different from C/C++ though (the OpenMP implementations are generally in C and use C pointers anyway).

Maybe you can store the result in an array and provide the index of the item to the task (private index and shared array). The array can be deleted later. This assume the whole array does not take too much space.

Shared variables cannot run out of scope before all tasks accessing the variable have finished. Put a taskwait at the end of the subroutine to fix the issue. The default behavior of the Intel runtime is to enqueue up to 255 tasks before starting to work on a newly created task. This should explain why the master thread does not leave the subroutine earlier.

According to the comments and some additional tests I made, it turns out that a routine where some tasks have been spawned must not be exited until all tasks are completed. A solution is to put a taskwait directive at the end of the routine, but it doesn't fit my original objective, where I wanted the master thread to execute all the iterations of sub1() while the tasks were being executed. I ended up with a solution that consist in enclosing the call to sub2()in a task: that way, the master thread can continue executing without waiting for sub2() to exit:
type(mytype) :: x(10)

!$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT(SHARED)
!$OMP MASTER
do i = 1, 10
   call sub1(x(i)) ! some stuff that cannot be parallelized
   !$OMP TASK
   call sub2(x(i)) ! some stuff that can be parallelized once sub1 has completed
   !$OMP END TASK
!$OMP END MASTER
!$OMP END PARALLEL

[.....]

subroutine sub2(x)
   type(mytype), intent(inout) :: x
   integer :: j, k
   integer, allocatable :: v(:)
   allocate( v(10000) ) 
   v(:) = ... ! filling up v
   do j = 1, 1000
      !$OMP TASK DEFAULT(NONE) SHARED(x) PRIVATE(k) FIRSTPRIVATE(j,v)
         !...working on x
      !$OMP END TASK
   end do
   !$OMP TASKWAIT 
end subroutine

Update
After more tests and with the help of the other answers and comments I have now a better understanding of the problem.
First, the problem comes only from the shared variables, not from the firstprivate (and obviously not from the private) ones. Even if the tasks effectively starts after the exit of sub2(), the firstprivate variables are correctly initialized (it seems that the task scheduler builds the whole environment of the task when it creates it, not when it starts it).
More important, I am actually passing an array section, not a scalar, and this has some consequences. The original code was therefore actually more like this (focusing here on the shared variables):
type(mytype) :: x(100)

!$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT(SHARED)
!$OMP MASTER
do i = 1, 100, 10
   call sub1( x(i:i+9) ) ! some stuff that cannot be parallelized
   call sub2( x(i:i+9) ) ! some stuff that can be parallelized once sub1 has completed
!$OMP END MASTER
!$OMP END PARALLEL

[.....]

subroutine sub2(x2)
   type(mytype), intent(inout) :: x2(:) ! assumed shape interface
   type(mytype), allocatable :: y(:) ! local array
   allocate( y(size(x)) ) 
   do j = 1, 1000
      !$OMP TASK DEFAULT(NONE) SHARED(x2,y)
         !...working on x2, y being a work array
      !$OMP END TASK
   end do
end subroutine

What happens with y(:) is easy: once sub2() exits, y is out of scope and any reference to it has chances to fail or result in garbage.
About x2(:): the dummy argument x2(:) is "assumed shape", which means that what is actually passed to sub2() is not a simple address (C pointer) but a (hidden) temporary array descriptor (which contains the sizes, the rank, the strides... in addition to the address). Once sub2() exits the address is still valid, but it can no longer be read because the array descriptor does no longer exist.
Replacing x2(:) by x2(*) (assumed size interface) or x2(n) (explicit shape interface) can solve the problem. These are the legacy interfaces of Fortran, and in this case only the base address is passed, not a descriptor. But it also depends on how the routine is called:

call sub2( x2(i:i+9) ) : what is passed is a contiguous array section. In this case the compilers generally just pass the address of x2(i) beyond the scene, so everything is OK
call sub2( x2(i) ) : the compilation would fail, because a scalar is passed while an array is expected.
call sub2( x2(i:i+9:3) ) : what is passed is a non-contiguous array section. But since both x(*)andx(n)assume a contiguous array, the compiler will create a temporary contiguous copy ofx2(i:i+9:3)and pass the address of this copy. Whensub2()` exits the temporary copy gets out of scope and the address gets useless.

Notes

Even if a contiguous section is passed, the compiler is in theory free to make a temporary copy anyway (and whichever the interface), which means that one can never be 100% sure...
With the x2(:) assumed shape interface, passing a whole array (call sub2( x2 )) is probably safer, as the compiler can pass the existing array descriptor instead of creating a temporary descriptor that is destroyed when sub2() exits. However not all arrays have a descriptor (it's compiler dependent, but static arrays do not necessarily need one).

When using the x2(:) assumed shape interface there's maybe a solution based on Fortran pointers (quickly tested, it seems to work, but more tests would be needed to be sure):
type(mytype), TARGET :: x(100)

!$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT(SHARED)
!$OMP MASTER
do i = 1, 100, 10
   call sub1( x(i:i+9) ) ! some stuff that cannot be parallelized
   call sub2( x(i:i+9) ) ! some stuff that can be parallelized once sub1 has completed
!$OMP END MASTER
!$OMP END PARALLEL

[.....]

subroutine sub2(x2)
   type(mytype), intent(inout), TARGET :: x2(:) ! assumed shape interface
   type(mytype), allocatable :: y(:) ! local array
   type(mytype), POINTER :: p(:)
   allocate( y(size(x)) ) 
   p => x2
   do j = 1, 1000
      !$OMP TASK DEFAULT(NONE) SHARED(y), FIRSTPRIVATE(p)
         !...working on p, y being a work array
      !$OMP END TASK
   end do
end subroutine

Fortran pointers are different from C, there's no double, triple,.. pointer. b => a ; c => b is the same as b => a ; c => a (hence, after b => null(), c is still associated to a). Hence, in the above example p is effectively pointing to the original x(i:i+9) section, even after x2 goes out of scope. Then, making it firstprivate ensures that the tasks still have valid private copies even after sub2() has exited. And since p is just a pointer, this a light (shallow) copy (in practice the copy of a descriptor); making directly x2 firstprivate would be possible, but it would be a deep copy (unaffordable if x2 uses a lot of memory).
Note that per the standard, this approach requires the original x array to have the target attribute. AFAIK, when both the actual and the dummy arguments have the target attribute, the compiler is not allowed to make a temporary copy.

Do you need identical private copies of v for each task? Otherwise it could make sense to make v shared or private.

@Joachim Indeed yes, v could be shared, as I don't modify it in the tasks. I initially set it firstprivate because I thought the master thread could exit the routine early and that a shared v would get out of scope. But with the taskwait it can no longer happen...

I'm not a Fortran programmer, just sometimes listening to Fortran folks. The issue might be related to the issue of passing array slices to non-blocking MPI communication routines. While the array itself is still there, the array slice meta information runs out of scope as soon as the routine returns. For me, sub2(x(i)) looks like passing an array slice. With the additional task, you now introduced a new scope for the array slice. If you would call sub2(x, i) instead, rearranging sub2 to do the array access, if might solve your scoping issue.

"For me, sub2(x(i)) looks like passing an array slice." It isn't. It is passing a scalar array element.

No MPI is visible in the code shown. This problem of noncontiguous array sections was fixed in MPI3 with modern Fortran interfaces to MPI and was always preventable by using MPI derived typpes and passing one element exactly as sub2(x(i)) - that is not a problem. Also, the array temporary section does not survive even in the calling code. It is only valid during the code itself. So even calling MPI_Wait right after the nonblocking call with an array section leads to an immediate crash.

So, you agree that the lifetime of x(I) is limited to the duration of the sub2 call, and sub2 cannot write to x(I) after return? By calling sub2(x, I), could sub2 access x(I) even after return from sub2?

No, it is not. Calling sub2(x(i)) does not cause creation of any temporary because the subroutine must get access to other elements of the array and that is in practice possible only by passing a pointer to the original (or by copying the whole array, but that is pure theory). Passing x(i) is precisely what is used in MPI "classic" to avoid the problems with array sections.

@VladimirFГероямслава The right statement is rather: "Calling sub2(x(i)) does not cause creation of any temporary in practice with usual compilers". For, the standard does not specify how the arguments are passed, and in (almost) any case the compilers are allowed to make a temporary copy. Passing x(i) and accessing other elements than this one was/is a common practice, but it's nonetheless illegal code per the standard.

OK, it turns out that in my real code I am actually passing an array section, not a scalar, and that is a part of the problem. I will update my answer.

@PierU That's why I wrote "that is in practice possible only by passing a pointer to the original (or by copying the whole array, but that is pure theory)" Making just a copy of the single element is not possible here. Only a copy of the whole array would have to be made.
